# Can a disjoint union of two sets be a connected graph?

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

Can A ⊎ B, where |A| ≠ |B|, be a complete graph? There is a lemma about Hamiltonian cycles which states:

If G = (A ⊎ B| E) is a bipartite graph, |A| ≠ |B|, then there is no Hamiltonian cycle in G.

A union of disjoint graphs (as far as I know that is what ⊎ implies), cannot contain a Hamiltonian cycle, because the graph wouldn't be connected. If so, how is the graph being bipartite and |A| ≠ |B| even relevant?

Comment: Completeness and connectedness are very distinct concepts. Are you sure you are not mixing them up?

Comment: @MBW You are right, I was mixing them up. Thank you!

Comment: Regarding your question, the notation G = (A ⊎ B| E) seems to imply that the edges only connect vertices from $A$ to $B$, but never two vertices in $A$ or two vertices in $B$. That is, the graph is bipartite and the partitions are $A$ and $B$. $|A| \neq |B|$ matters because a Hamiltonian path will traverse each vertex once but it must alternate between vertices of A and B since the graph is bipartite. You cannot create this alternating sequence with all elements of both if they don't contain the same number of elements

Comment: @MBW I think you are right. Why don't you add that as answer so I can accept it?